# VBA can't seem to detect my cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table with data from Column A to G. After inserting 2 new columns in "A:B", I want to copy paste the values from Column I (which was initially in Column G) to Column A.
But something seems wrong with my "Range(lrow, "A")" in particular and I can't figure it out. I know this might look like an amatuer mistake but I was hoping if somebody could kindly point out where I went wrong. Thanks in advance!!

```
        Sub Merge()
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Columns("A:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range(lRow, "A").Value = Range(Range("I1"),Range("I1").End(xlDown)).Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `Range("A1:A" & lRow).Value = Range("I1:I" & lRow).Value`? (Or, written another way, `Range("A1").Resize(lRow, 1).Value = Range("I1").Resize(lRow, 1).Value`.)

Comment: Ah this was what I was looking for!! Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In working with dynamically changing rows or columns in VBA I usually prefer to use:

```
Range(Cells(row,col), Cells(row,col))
```

This is much more reliable than trying to calculate letter-number cell designations that Excel records for you. Simply `Dim row` and `Dim col` and use these to make all of your references to cells.

This website goes into far more detail than I have:
https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-range-cells/

Comment: I have already found the answer, but the link that you have provided me is an extremely insightful as well. Will take a closer look when i have the time thanks :)

Comment: @Ben I'm glad I could help!